# Sage 100 & SAP Crystal Reports 2016 - Generate running total on column that uses Sum() already

Tags: crystal-reports

I am trying to generate a conditional running total that consists of a final cost for all items on a Bill of Materials report. Right now, I have a column named Shortage that calculates how much of an item needs to be purchased by subtracting the needed amount by the current amount in the warehouse (database). Code for this formula is below:
[@Shortage formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRUTK.png).
From what I understand there are two separate groups/warehouses - the Sum() in that formula pulls an on-hand quantity based off of the group and then subtracts it from the total quantity needed for the BOM.

Next, I created another formula named unitCostQty that simply multiplies the Shortage column by the cost of the component. This gives me the total cost for purchasing all needed quantities of a given item.

I would like to get a conditional running total of the unitCostQty so that I can get a total cost of every needed item. It's conditional because I only want to add items to the total that have shortages. As far as I can tell the conditional summation is working correctly. Code below:
[@unitCostQty formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5cQPg.png)

I can't seem to get the column I want to be summed as intended because SAP Crystal Reports only allow single-level summaries. The Sum() function in the Shortages column is not allowing me to sum the way I want (I think).

I've tried making a totalCost Running Total field but it does not account for items with a larger quantity than 1. For example, if I have a list of 3 types of items:

| Code | Cost per Item | Shortage |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | $150 | 2 |
| 456 | $100 | 1 |
| 789 | $25 | 1 |

My running total should be 150(2) + 100(1) + 25(1) = $425 but my current solution outputs $275.